# jquery Select2 working with large data is not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

I have to implement jquery select2 on a drop down which has more than 8000 items.  I tried possible solutions and stuck somewhere, Actually the drop down has some static function to bring all the items to it.  So I want to get all the items in a list.

`var data = [];
    $("select[name='stock_id'] option").each(function(){
        var value= $(this).val();
        var txt = $(this).text();
        data.push({id: ""+value, text: ""+txt});
    });`

`data` will keep all the existing options list in it.  Now I want to show it 100 and when user scroll down to last. It will expand to show another 100 items. For that,  I have used `lodash` and code

```
$("#_stock_id_edit").select2({
initSelection: function(element, callback) {
  var selection = _.find(data, function(metric){ 
  return metric.id === element.val();
})
callback(selection);
 },

query: function(options){
var pageSize = 100;
var startIndex  = (options.page - 1) * pageSize;
var filteredData = data;

if( options.term && options.term.length > 0 ){
  if( !options.context ){
    var term = options.term.toLowerCase();
    options.context = data.filter( function(metric){
      return ( metric.text.toLowerCase().indexOf(term) !== -1 );
    });
  }
  filteredData = options.context;
}

options.callback({
  context: filteredData,
  results: filteredData.slice(startIndex, startIndex + pageSize),
  more: (startIndex + pageSize) < filteredData.length
});
}
});
```

When I run this code, it shows an empty dropdown. 
here is my included things.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.16.6/lodash.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/css/select2.css">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/js/select2.full.js"></script>
```

Here is Fiddle link 
[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jd7k10w5/)

**Note :**  My question may be exist. but my code is different. Please try to answer in this code. Also I Can't use AJAX method. So please dont Suggest me the AJAX things Here.

Comment: Don't mean to burst your bubble here, but 8000 items in a drop down is a huge flaw in design. I kinda feel sorry for your users.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. it actually done with recent select2 in ajax method.